# SQL COUNT with values from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following two tables:

comments

| comment_post_ID | status | comment_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | complete | course_status |
| 2 | complete | course_status |
| a1 | complete | lesson_status |
| a2 | passed | lesson_status |
| a3 | in-progress | lesson_status |

postmeta

| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | lesson_course | 1 |
| a2 | lesson_course | 1 |
| a3 | lesson_course | 2 |

The Result should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [comment_post_ID] => 1
            [lessoncomplete] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [comment_post_ID] => 2
            [lessoncomplete] => 0
        )
```

What I want is the count of all lessons with status complete or passed by the comment_post_ID. The postmeta table is needed for which lesson belongs to which course. That's where I am so far:

```
SELECT
c.comment_post_ID,

/* Lektionen abgeschlossen*/
(SELECT Count(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_type = 'lesson_status' AND status IN ('passed', 'complete')) AS lessoncomplete

FROM comments c

WHERE c.comment_type = 'course_status'
```

I don't even know if I'm on the right way so every help is much appreciated! Later on I also want to calculate something in the same query with the count of the completed lessons...

Answer (score 0):

I have crafted some SQL Schema from your example:
I think this query might bring you closer to what you desire:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `postmeta` (
`post_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`meta_key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`meta_value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
 ('a1', 'lesson_course', '1'),
  ('a2', 'lesson_course', '1'),
  ('a3', 'lesson_course', '2');
  
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
`comment_post_ID` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`comment_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`comment_post_ID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment_post_ID`, `status`, `comment_type`) VALUES
  ('1', 'complete', 'course_status'),
  ('2', 'complete', 'course_status'),
  ('a1', 'complete', 'lesson_status'),
  ('a2', 'passed', 'lesson_status'),
  ('a3', 'in-progress', 'lesson_status');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
(
SELECT COUNT(comment_post_ID) FROM comments c
WHERE c.status = 'passed'
)+(
SELECT COUNT(comment_post_ID) FROM comments c
WHERE c.status = 'complete') AS Lesson_Completed;


| Lesson_Completed |
| ---------------- |
| 4                |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mnvZ5ER6XC9A2HXiTKURrd/3)

Why do you need table postmeta?